# Comparison operator "==" for value equality or reference equality?

Tags: python, reference, equality, semantics

So many tutorials have stated that the `==` comparison operator is for value equality, like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085656/11887333), quote:

> - `==` is for *value equality*. Use it when you would like to know if two objects have the same value.
> - `is` is for *reference equality*. Use it when you would like to know if two references refer to the same object.

However, I found that the Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__) says that:

> `x==y` calls `x.__eq__(y)`. By default, `object` implements `__eq__()` by using `is`, returning `NotImplemented` in the case of a false comparison: `True if x is y else NotImplemented`."

It seems the default behavior of the `==` operator is to compare the reference quality like the `is` operator, which contradicts what these tutorials say.

So what exactly should I use `==` for? value equality or reference equality? Or it just depends on how you implement the `__eq__` method.

---

I think the doc of [Value comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) has illustrated this question clearly:

> The operators `<`, `>`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`, and `!=` compare the values of two objects. The value of an object is a rather abstract notion in Python. Comparison operators implement a particular notion of what the value of an object is. One can think of them as defining the value of an object indirectly, by means of their comparison implementation.

> The behavior of the default equality comparison, that instances with different identities are always unequal, may be in contrast to what types will need that have a sensible definition of object value and value-based equality. Such types will need to customize their comparison behavior, and in fact, a number of built-in types have done that.

> The default behavior for equality comparison (`==` and `!=`) is based on the identity of the objects. Hence, equality comparison of instances with the same identity results in equality, and equality comparison of instances with different identities results in inequality. A motivation for this default behavior is the desire that all objects should be reflexive (i.e. `x is y` implies `x == y`).

It also includes a list that describes the comparison behavior of the most important built-in types like numbers, strings and sequences, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It solely depends on what `__eq__` does. The default `__eq__` of type `object` behaves like `is`. Some builtin datatypes use their own implementation. For example, two lists are equal if all their values are equal. You just have to know this.

Answer (score 3):

`object` implements `__eq__()` by using `is`, but many classes in the standard library implement `__eq__()` using value equality. E.g.:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l3 = l1
>>> l1 is l2
False
>>> l1 == l2
True
>>> l1 is l3
True
```

In your own classes, you can implement `__eq__()` as it makes sense, e.g.:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.x
```

Answer (score 0):

To add your thought process with a simple definition ,

The Equality operator `==` compares the values of both the operands and checks for value equality. Whereas the `is` operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not (present in the same memory location).

In a nutshell, `is` checks whether two references point to the same object or not.`==` checks whether two objects have the same value or not.

For example:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=a        #a and b point to the same object
c=list(a)  #c points to different object 

if a==b:
    print('#')   #output:#
if a is b:
    print('##')  #output:## 
if a==c:
    print('###') #output:## 
if a is c:
    print('####') #no output as c and a point to different object
```

Answer (score -1):

```
one = 1
a = one
b = one
if (a == b): # this if works like this: if (1 == 1)
if (a is 1): # this if works like this: if (int.object(1, memory_location:somewhere) == int.object(1, memory_location:variable.one))
```

thus, **a is 1** won't work because its arguments are not pointing to the same location.

Comment: `a is 1` raises a `SyntaxWarning` (tested in Python 3.9)

Comment: TIL about `SyntaxWarning`. Neat. Based on a quick test, it looks like that's generated on `a is 1` starting with Python 3.8.

Comment: Actually, `a is 1` returns `True` from my test, I think it's because Python has a cache pool for common integers like `1` and they are only created once.